# Iterate blockwise through mongodb results

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a mongodb query which fetchs about 50,000 big documents.
This is to much for my RAM and so the computer slows down.

Now I want to iterate blockwise through the mongodb result.
I want to fetch the first 1000 docs and proccess them and then the next 1000 an so on.

1. Is this the best way to handle hugh sizes of data? Or should I better take one after the other?

I tried the following:

```
MongoCursor<MyDocument> items = collection.Find(query);
long count = items.Count();
int stepSize = 1000;

for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling((double)count / stepSize); i++)
{
    List<MyDocument> list = items.SetSkip(i * stepSize).SetLimit(stepSize).ToList();
    // process the 1000 ...
}
```

But this code didn't work. I got the following error:

> A MongoCursor object cannot be modified once it has been frozen.

2. How to fix this Problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you profesor79 for your hint.

Now I am able to get it blockwise, so I started a measure with an unexpected result.

Result set had 39,500 Documents

First test: Step size of 1000 Documents:

```
int stepSize = 1000;
long start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling((double)count / stepSize); i++)
{
    List<MyDocument> list = collection.Find(query).SetSkip(i * stepSize).SetLimit(stepSize).ToList();
}
long end = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
Debug.WriteLine("Step 1000 --> " + new TimeSpan(end - start));
// Step 1000 --> 00:00:41.1731168
```

Second test: Step size of 2000 Documents:

```
int stepSize = 2000;
long start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling((double)count / stepSize); i++)
{
    List<MyDocument> list = collection.Find(query).SetSkip(i * stepSize).SetLimit(stepSize).ToList();
}
long end = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
Debug.WriteLine("Step 2000 --> " + new TimeSpan(end - start));
// Step 2000 --> 00:00:42.1772173
```

Third test: Step size of 5000 Documents:

```
int stepSize = 5000;
long start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling((double)count / stepSize); i++)
{
    List<MyDocument> list = collection.Find(query).SetSkip(i * stepSize).SetLimit(stepSize).ToList();
}
long end = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
Debug.WriteLine("Step 5000 --> " + new TimeSpan(end - start));
// Step 5000 --> 00:00:40.9530949
```

Last test: Step size of 1 Document:

```
long start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
foreach (MyDocument item in collection.Find(query))
{

}
long end = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
Debug.WriteLine("Step 1 --> " + new TimeSpan(end - start));
// Step 1 --> 00:00:39.6329629
```

So it seems that it makes no sense to use blocks.
Everything was roughly the same fast.
I received similar times when running the test again.

The only thing that uses a hugh amount of RAM is doing this:

```
collection.Find(query)).ToList();
```

ToList had cached all in the RAM.

Hope it helps other peoples.

Answer (score 3):

you could use this approach

```
        var count = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Count();
        var stepSize = 1000;

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling((double)count / stepSize); i++)
        {
            // put your query here      \/\/\/\/\/\/
            var list = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Skip(i * stepSize).Limit(stepSize).ToList();
            // process the 1000 ...
        }
```

as you are interested to get and process 
driver 2.2.4

Comment: This seems to work. But is this the best solution for going through all results? Is this faster then iterating through each result document? Or what is the best stepSize for doing this? Do I have to find it out on my own or is there already any experience? Thanks for help

Comment: that's a very good question as usually try to find optimum amount of  data,  and flexible process flow. The huge dependency here is document size - so in this case you could even start new task to process data in parallel using TPL